# Why are beans in Spring creating for procedural methods?

Tags: java, spring, oop

Most often, when I see a web application using mvc and the spring framework, it contains layers such as services and repositories, which for the most part look like utility methods in a class and this class almost never has a state. My question is, why is this procedural code not in static methods? This is not my suggestion to do so, I just want to know it in order to form a more complete picture of this world.

Comment: See https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/364496/are-spring-beans-declared-as-static-a-poor-design-choice

Comment: Thank you! I think I should read about the disadvantages of static methods in oop